# Работа Split C#

Tags: c#, строки, split

У меня есть строка `"140-hp, 3.1-liter V-6 (regular gas),\r\n170-hp, 5.0-liter V-8 (regular gas)"` и мне надо выполнить Split до `,\r`. Как это реализовать
Пытался сделать так `AvailableEngines.GetText().Split(new char[] {',\r'})` но не принимает много параметров. Просто обрезать последний символ нельзя.

Comment: `.Split(new string[] {",\r"}, StringSplitOptions.None)`

Comment: @Igor Too many character literal

Comment: Вы неточно скопировали код, из моего комментария. Попробуйте еще раз :).

Comment: @ПавелКушнеревич **не** char, а **string**  потому что надо

Comment: @Igor а не подскажите как учесть ещё пробел перед данной конструкцией ?

Comment: @ПавелКушнеревич объясните, что понимается под словом "учесть" - в Вашем примере строки пробелов перед запятой нет

Comment: @Igor а если бы допустим был

Comment: @ПавелКушнеревич я бы делал `Split` по ",", а потом `Trim` получившимся строкам https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @ПавелКушнеревич - а, не заметил, что так не сработает. Тогда - делать `Split` как сейчас, а потом - `Trim`.

Comment: Ей-богу, это выглядит как два строго типизированных объекта: читаем ReadLine построчно, каждую обрабатываем единообразно разбивая поля (сепаратор - запятая, тримая каждое поле). Недоумеваю, где в практике могло понадобится лететь из Питера в Москву через Магадан, создавая себе самому сложности на ровном месте. Или это сугубо учебное, тренировочное задание?

Comment: @AK я паршу сайт Cars.com и там нужно сравнить характеристики машины, иногда на на следующей строке бывает лишняя инофрмация)

Comment: @Igor спасибо большое)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
string[] separator = new string[] { ",\r" };
AvailableEngines.GetText().Split(separator, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Comment: @Igor естественно System.String[]. Потому и исправил:)

Comment: Пардон, писал комментарий до того, как увидел Вашу правку.

Comment: Спасибо большое)